# How to determine a contract address with a predefined transaction?

Tags: solidity, web3.py

In ERC-820 (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/820) a transaction is given which on raw send deploys a contract at a predefined address fro all chains. This deployment contract then deploys the Registry contract at a predefined address.

Now for the questions:

1. How is this possible? I assume it's because it's a signed transaction and so the address of the deployer is always the same?
2. If I try to web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x...') this, it doesn't work for a private testrpc chain, why?
3. In general, shouldn't this be best practice for all projects to give the raw transaction to have the same contract address in every chain?

Comment: Sorry, that was dumb, so, for question 1: yes, it's because it's signed already
For question 2: I didn't send enough ETH to the deployment address....
questions 3 is still open and valid. I think it's a very good pattern to deploy contracts like this

Comment: So could you please edit you question to leave only the 3rd one ?